# Servlet import error messages in Java?

Tags: java, servlets

I am just starting to develop a simple servlet but am receiving errors on the following imports. The error states that the imports cannot be found. Do I have to download a servlet jar file or some other pluggin for Eclipse? I am really new to the servlet part of java. I want to have one button call a simple method that writes one line of code to a text file but first I have to be able to make a servlet.

Code

```
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

Comment: You need to point to your application servers runtime.

Comment: I am testing this on my own personal computer. Where do I find the applciation servers runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add application server runtime to your IDE classpath. For instance:
1. install tomcat from eclipse (servers view -> new server) and follow the result.
2. Go to Project properties -> java build path -> Libraries -> add library and select "Apache Tomcat .."